# Panda coding - sorting values and creating a new df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input -

| item | year | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2000 | 10 |
| a | 2001 | 12 |
| a | 2002 | 15 |
| b | 2000 | 5 |
| b | 2001 | 5 |
| b | 2002 | 4 |

desired output -

| item | price in 2000 | price in 2002 | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 15 | 5 |
| b | 5 | 4 | -1 |

Need help with code.
Can someone help get this output? This is smaller representation of an actual dataset i'm working with.

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like it would involve `pd.pivot_table` to make a column for each year, then adding the last column like `df['difference'] = df[2002] - df[2000]`.

Comment: Please no pictures for what can be shared as text. See [ask] for guidance. Also please state what difficulty you are experiencing, so that we may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your dataframe before reshape it with `pivot`:

```
out = (df[df['year'].isin([2000, 2002])]
          .pivot(index='item', columns='year', values='price')
          .add_prefix('price in ').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
          .assign(difference=lambda x: x['price in 2002'] - x['price in 2000']))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  item  price in 2000  price in 2002  difference
0    a             10             15           5
1    b              5              4          -1
```

Step-by-step:

```
# 1. Keep only 2000 and 2002
>>> out = df[df['year'].isin([2000, 2002])]
  item  year  price
0    a  2000     10
2    a  2002     15
3    b  2000      5
5    b  2002      4

# 2. Reshape your dataframe from long to wide
>>> out = out.pivot(index='item', columns='year', values='price')
year  2000  2002
item            
a       10    15
b        5     4

# 3. Some aesthetics
>>> out = out.add_prefix('price in ').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
  item  price in 2000  price in 2002
0    a             10             15
1    b              5              4

# 4. Compute difference
>>> out = out.assign(difference=lambda x: x['price in 2002'] - x['price in 2000'])
  item  price in 2000  price in 2002  difference
0    a             10             15           5
1    b              5              4          -1
```